# Click all div layers insight div

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this html code hwich I would like to test with Selenium:

http://pastebin.com/LX5URz53

I would like to get all div layers insight div `boxes` How I can do this?

RemoteWebDriver driver = BrowserFactory.getDriver("chrome", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe");

```
    driver.get("http://jenkins.mws.com:8080");

    driver.switchTo().frame("iwg-game-full");

    WebDriverWait waitPage = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(steadinessOfElementLocated(By.id("ready")));

    element.click();

    if (element.isDisplayed())
{
    System.out.println("Play button is displayed");

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

    List<WebElement> childs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("div[id='boxes'] div"));

    for (int i = 0; i < childs.size(); i++)
    {
        WebElement get = childs.get(i);

        get.getText();
        System.out.println(">>>>> getText " + get.getText() + " " + get.getTagName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I implementaed loading of the page and pages navigation.

Comment: Could share your code as well??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use xpath - `"//div[@id='boxes']//div"` or css `"div[id='boxes'] div"`in `driver.findElements(By.....)` method.

Comment: Hall I can get all sub divs as a List?

Comment: You will get every div that is present inside the 'boxes' div irrespective of where they are located in the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: I updated my post. Now I get basicScreenResizeTest(org.selenium.google.PlayBoardTest): invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression div[id='boxes'] div because of the following error:

Comment: You are using the CSS expression that I had mentioned instead of the Xpath one. Use the first one which has the @ symbol.